# "operation on non-blocking socket would block" Database first NpgSQL EF Core

Tags: sockets, npgsql, ef-database-first

I am building an applikation with Xamarin, using a database built in postgres with EF Core (v 5.0.5)
When I try to run my CRUD operation "GetAllArticles" to show in my view, I get a break in  my repository with the error "operation on non-blocking socket would block".

I have tried changing this method a couple of time, with no success. I understand it ain't the prettiest, but please help!

I am a beginner and I'm not digging into using asynchronous methods until I get this to work first.

```
  public IEnumerable<ArticleRegistrationModel> GetAllArticles()
        {
            return _db.Articles.Select(
                s => new ArticleRegistrationModel
                {
                    ArticleId = s.ArticleId,
                    ArticleName = s.ArticleName,
                    Ean = s.Ean,
                    Plu = s.Plu,
                    Supplier = s.Supplier,
                    PurchasePrice = s.PurchasePrice,
                    RetailPrice = s.RetailPrice

                }
            ).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance this isn't an exception thrown out of Npgsql, but rather a first-chance internal exception happening inside Npgsql. Npgsql's implementation of synchronous Open involves catching this exception - this shouldn't have any effect on your code, and everything should run.

If you are certain this is an exception bubbling up to your code, please post a full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1183), @ShayRojansky is right. The exception is coming from .NET's socket API and Npgsql can't stop it from being thrown. Their advice is to ignore the exception.